# Looking for a better way to log wait() and notify() methods

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, locking, wrapper

I am trying to print to console whenever the wait, notify, and notifyAll methods in Object class are invoked and returned. To achieve this, I have created a wrapper class that invokes the wait, notify and notifyAll methods on behalf of the lock object. I then use the methods on the wrapper instead of the wait, notify and notifyAll. Here's my best attempt at this,

Thread One runs Runnable r1

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                // wait not wrapped in while loop for brevity.
                //lock.wait(); 
                lock.objWrapper.waitNew(); // Use the wrapper method instead of wait()
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
};
```

Thread Two runs Runnable r2

```
Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            //lock.notifyAll();
            lock.objWrapper.notifyAllNew(); // Use the wrapper method instead of notifyAll()
        }
    }
};
```

The class Lock is defined as,

```
public class Lock {
    ObjWrapper objWrapper = new ObjWrapper(this);
    // shared data here
}

Lock lock = new Lock();
```

The wrapper class is defined as,

```
public class ObjWrapper {
    Object obj = null;

    ObjWrapper(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("New Object wrapper created: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " at time: " + Instant.now());
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void waitNew() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Entering Object::wait: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " at time: " + Instant.now());
        obj.wait();
        System.out.println("Exiting Object::wait: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " at time: " + Instant.now());
    }

    public void notifyNew() {
        System.out.println("Entering Object::notify: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " at time: " + Instant.now());
        obj.notify();
        System.out.println("Exiting Object::notify: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " at time: " + Instant.now());
    }

    public void notifyAllNew() {
        System.out.println("Entering Object::notifyAll: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " at time: " + Instant.now());
        obj.notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Exiting Object::notifyAll: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread() + " at time: " + Instant.now());
    }
}
```

And finally, start the threads using,

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    t1.setName("Thread One");
    t1.start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t2.setName("Thread Two");
    t2.start();
```

The output on console,

```
New Object wrapper created: Thread: Thread[main,5,main] at time: 2017-03-19T22:48:28.771Z
Entering Object::wait: Thread: Thread[Thread One,5,main] at time: 2017-03-19T22:48:28.844Z
Entering Object::notifyAll: Thread: Thread[Thread Two,5,main] at time: 2017-03-19T22:48:31.845Z
Exiting Object::notifyAll: Thread: Thread[Thread Two,5,main] at time: 2017-03-19T22:48:31.845Z
Exiting Object::wait: Thread: Thread[Thread One,5,main] at time: 2017-03-19T22:48:31.845Z
```

My questions are,

1. Is there any other better way of doing this?
2. Are there any edge cases that will break when using the ObjWrapper?

Edit:
 I am not looking for better ways to lock objects. Just better ways to log the invocations of `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` methods specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1, I would rather subclass [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), then override the *signal* and *await* methods, because with this approach, you lose anyway the possibility to use the keyword synchronized on method.

Regarding question 2, the main edge case here I can see here is that you are bound by [intrinsic lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and intrinsic condition queue. A big caveat in my opinion is that if you wish to use [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and/or [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), you are going to have to write new wrappers (which might not be straightforward), risking to introduce more complexity, and more issues.

Now as you are probably already aware, I'd rather suggest sticking to higher level APIs, i.e., Latches, Semaphores, Barriers, ConcurrentCollection, and so on and so forth, and to stay away as long as possible from low level thread management as it tends to get tricky really fast.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please look at my edit. I am specifically interested in the `wait()` and `notify()` methods in Object class and would like to know when they are invoked.

Comment: They are invoked when you call them, which is why I'm not sure about the wrapping part. I think you are trying to check when a thread starts running after a notify/notifyAll call, correct me if I'm wrong, which is a much broader topic

Comment: You are right, I want a handle on a thread when it goes from running state to waiting state and vice versa. The only hook into the code I have is the debug statements. With these constraints in mind, I am left with logging the invocations of `wait` and `notify`